# addEventListener('popstate') is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to restrict browser back button.

I have used below code to restrict.

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
global.window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
});
```

Code worked really well with chrome but it is not working in IE11

kindly assist.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: browser back restriction..
on click of browser back button still it goes back to previous page in IE 11.
where as in chrome its not as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer example below is working in chrome and IE both.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Disable Back Button in Browser - Online Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       div{
  margin:auto;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
h1{
  text-align:center;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
p{
  text-align:center;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
<h1><a href="http://www.justwebcode.com" rel="index,follow">Just Web Code</a></h1>
  <p>Click on Browser Back Button to Check</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[How to disable browser back button using JavaScript](https://codepen.io/dhavalt10/pen/rGLBzB)

Note:- Try to run code locally, If you run the code from Stack overflow snippet than it will give an error.